# ¿Como obtener datos especificos de un array que se almacena en una Session en Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, array, session

Saludos chicos, el tema es sencillo necesito mostrar en una vista los datos de un array que esta en session, la cual contiene varios array.

Lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente:

Asi actualizo el array:

```
public function inscribir(Evento $evento, Request $request){
    $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
    $inscrito = [            
        'nombre'=>$request->get('nombre'),            
        'edad'=>$request->get('edad'),
        'cedula'=>$request->get('cedula'),
        ];
    $tienda[$inscrito['cedula']] = $inscrito;
    \Session::put('tienda', $tienda);

    //dd(\Session::get('tienda'));
    return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));


}
```

Asi lo envio a la vista:

```
public function index()
{
    $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
   // dd(\Session::get('tienda'));
    return view('tienda.tienda', compact('tienda'));
}
```

y asi intento mostrarlo:

```
@foreach($tienda as $inscrito)

                    @foreach($inscrito as $value)
                    <td> {{ $value }} </td>
                    @endforeach

                @endforeach
```

Me esta mostrando todo el array en la vista, pero lo que necesito es recorrer cada array y mostrar los datos específicos, aquí va la imagen de lo que esta recibiendo la vista como ejemplo con dd.

[image: Lo que recibe la vista:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontre la manera de mostrarlo en la vista, de la siguiente forma:

```
@foreach($tienda as $inscrito)
            <tr>                    
                <td>{{ $inscrito['nombre'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $inscrito['cedula'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $inscrito['edad'] }} </td>
            </tr>                       
@endforeach
```

Casi podría jurar que ya lo había probado.